# Angular 2 - datepickers don't work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I need a datepicker to my application. First I tried to add bootstrap datepicker, but it didn't work. Therefore I tried to use ngBootstrap, but it still doesn't work. When I click to the icon I didn't get an calendar. Icon is not working.

my code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
            name="dp" [(ngModel)]="modelDate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
    <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
        <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
Model: {{ modelDate | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem is a result of not importing the ngBootstrap libraries correctly.

I'm assuming you've added it to your project dependencies:

```
npm install ng-bootstrap
```

In your index.html file, you need to import the Bootstrap css files

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
```

You can get these here:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com

Download the package and copy the css files into your project root css directory (`/css/`would match the import statements above). You don't need the js files, as ng-bootstrap provides the required code.

In the component where you're using the nbgDatepicker, you need to import the library at the top

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

And then the date picker should work properly.

Comment: Now I get an error in console: GET http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap.min.css 
add:12 GET http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css 
add:13 GET http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css

Comment: Did you create the css directory at the project root beside the index.html file and put the bootstrap css files in there?